# Rcpp: how to pass complex number from R to cpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, complex-numbers

I want to pass complex numbers from R to my cpp code using Rcpp.  I try to pass complex numbers analogously as one can pass doubles and integers:

```
#include <complex>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

RcppExport SEXP mandelC(SEXP s_c) {
    std::complex<double> c = ComplexVector(s_c)[0];
}
```

However, the code does not compile and complains about:

```
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/share/R/include -fopenmp  -I/home/siim/lib/R/Rcpp/include     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c a.cpp -o a.o
a.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* mandelC(SEXP)’:
a.cpp:7:50: error: conversion from ‘Rcpp::traits::storage_type<15>::type {aka Rcomplex}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::complex<double>’ requested
std::complex<double> c = ComplexVector(s_c)[0];
                                              ^
```

Obviously, I do something wrong but I have been unable to find any
examples.  Anyone can point me to the correct path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing some pretty simple things:

```
R> cppFunction("ComplexVector doubleMe(ComplexVector x) { return x+x; }")
R> doubleMe(1+1i)
[1] 2+2i
R> doubleMe(c(1+1i, 2+2i))
[1] 2+2i 4+4i
R>
```

Remember that *everything* is a vector in a R, and scalars don't "really" exist: they are vectors of length one.  So for a single `complex` number you (still) pass a `ComplexVector` which happens to be of length one.

Check out the two packages by Baptiste which do complex math via RcppArmadillo--that "proves" that some the RcppArmadillo  interfaces work the way they should.

*Edit:* And if you *really* want a scalar, you can get it too:

```
R> cppFunction("std::complex<double> doubleMeScalar(std::complex<double> x) { 
+                                                   return x+x; }")
R> doubleMeScalar(1+1i)
[1] 2+2i
R>
```

Comment: OK, so you suggest not to pass general SEXP but ComplexVector instead, and do math with ComplexVector instead of std::complex?  Is there an easy way to fetch a single (scalar) std::complex out of ComplexVector?

Comment: Dear Mr Miller aka "@Hack-R" aka : you got flagged and suspended twice already; I ask to cease editing posts without prior consent.  Thank you.

Comment: @OttToomet: Do yourself a favour and speed-read the Rcpp Attributes vignettes.  You cannot possibly write more concise code than what I have shown here -- and where we take advantage of the fact that Rcpp converts things behinds the scenes for us. _Internally_ it will always be a `SEXP` transfer.  But I find the plain C interface too cumbersome, and you appear to have gotten lost in it too.  Rcpp keeps a lot of things that should be fairly simple ... just that: fairly simple.

Comment: PS And if you invoke `cppFunction()` with `verbose=TRUE` you see some of the generated code, as you would in a package where you use `compileAttributes()` to generate bindings.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, I was able to solve the issue for a single scalar.  In particular I want to use std::norm() and I haven't figured out how to use it for Rcpp::ComplexVector

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Please feel free to accept and/or upvote as you see fit.